# Converting a Hebrew month name to an English month name in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hebrew

I have to take user input in Hebrew (a month name) and convert it to an English month name. Is there any way to convert this (maybe using to_date and to_char) without a lookup table?

Update - following the suggestion for Norwegian I made this test, showing that the short Hebrew month names are longer than three characters! (I can only handle three character strings in this function)

```
with d as
(
select to_date('01' || lpad(rownum,2,'0') || '2011','DDMMYYYY') d from
(
select 1 from dual connect by level <=12
)
)
select to_char(d.d,'MON','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=HEBREW') heb_mon,
to_char(d.d,'MONTH','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') us_mon
from d;
```

Which produced this data

```
ינואר   JAN
פברואר  FEB
מרץ     MAR
אפריל   APR
מאי     MAY
יוני    JUN
יולי    JUL
אוגוסט  AUG
ספטמבר  SEP
אוקטובר OCT
נובמבר  NOV
דצמבר   DEC
```

Comment: Um, given that the Hebrew months are different lengths to the english months, and start on different days, there isn't a 1-1 relationship between them. A Hebrew month can extend over two English months, and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry - I meant the Hebrew words for the English months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first thing that came to my mind. I don't know enough hebrew to test with hebrew values, but this seems to work with norwegian:

```
with test_norwegian as (
  select 'januar' month
  from dual
)
select 
to_char(
  to_date('1 '||test_norwegian.month||' 2011', 'dd month yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=NORWEGIAN')
  , 'month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=NORWEGIAN') norwegian_month
,to_char(
  to_date('1 '||test_norwegian.month||' 2011', 'dd month yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=NORWEGIAN')
  , 'month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') american_month
from test_norwegian
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick scan of the [Wikipedia Article: Hebrew calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) it seems reasonable to say that the Hebrew calendar does not operate the same way as the Gregorian calendar.  Examples include:

- There is no leap month in the Gregorian calendar for the year 5771.
- Gregorian months are fixed length.  Since they are based on lunar cycles, not all Hebrew months are fixed length.

**If you want to convert between Hebrew and Gregorian month names, You will first need to convert from a Hebrew date to a Gregorian date then determine the Gregorian month.**

A google search for "convert from hebrew date to gregorian date" produces what appears to be a large number of tools for converting between these calendars.

Here is an sourceforge project that may apply [hebcal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hebcal/)

Comment: Thanks - it has to be Oracle SQL I am afraid, as it's for a special purpose tool.

Comment: You may have to write your own conversion utility in PL/SQL.  Consider asking on Oracle forums, somebody else may have done this already.